# Filter PowerShell command Output

Tags: powershell, scripting

I want to change a mapped drive remote path. but I'm unable to filter the remote path property. Is there any way I can filter all the mapped drives remote path only so, later on, I can run a foreach loop to change the values? Thanks.

```
    Get-Item -Path HKCU:\Network | Where-Object -FilterScript {'RemotePath'}


    Hive: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network


Name                           Property                                                                                                                                                       
----                           --------                                                                                                                                                       
Z                              RemotePath     : \\IAPC\Users\IA\Documents\10                                                                                                                  
                               UserName       :                                                                                                                                               
                               ProviderName   : Microsoft Windows Network                                                                                                                     
                               ProviderType   : 131072                                                                                                                                        
                               ConnectionType : 1                                                                                                                                             
                               ConnectFlags   : 0                                                                                                                                             
                               DeferFlags     : 4                                                                                                                                             
                               UseOptions     : {68, 101, 102, 67...}                                                                                                                         



PS HKCU:\Network>
```

Only interested in name of the network drive with RemotePath (under Property column)

Answer (score 1):

The following outputs `[pscustomobject]` instances representing the values of those registry subkeys of `HKCU:\Network` whose `RemotePath` value is non-empty:

```sh
Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Network\* | Where-Object RemotePath
```

To get just the drive-name-remote-path pairs:

```sh
Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Network\* | Where-Object RemotePath | 
  Select-Object PSChildName, RemotePath
```

Note: The `PSChildName` property contains the drive letter of each mapping (it is the name of the subkey whose values are being returned).

---

To **loop over all mappings of interest** and **update them by replacing the server-name component**:

```sh
$oldServer = '\\IAPC\'
$newServer = '\\localhost\'
# CAVEAT: This instantly updates your drive mappings.
#         You can add -WhatIf to the Set-ItemProperty call,
#         to *preview* the operation, but it will only show the
#         target registry key and value, not the new data.
Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Network\* | Where-Object RemotePath | ForEach-Object {
  $driveLetter, $remotePath = $_.PSChildName, $_.RemotePath
  Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath HKCU:\Network\$driveLetter RemotePath ($remotePath -replace [regex]::Escape($oldServer), $newServer)
}
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

- `Where-Object -FilterScript {'RemotePath'}` is a *no-op*, because *any* input meets the criterion `'RemotePath'`, which, as a non-empty string literal is invariably `$true` when interpreted as a Boolean. To access a *property* on the *current* input object, you need to use [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_): `{ $_.RemotePath }`

  - It is only with the *simplified syntax*, shown above, which doesn't use a script block (`{ ... }`) that the string argument given is *implicitly* interpreted as the name of the property to access on the input object at hand.
- `Get-Item -Path HKCU:\Network` only targets the root key of all network mappings *itself*, not the subkeys that define the actual mappings.

  - In your case you're also interested in the `RemotePath` *value* of each subkey, which [`Get-ItemProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itemproperty) provides for all subkeys, targeted with a *wildcard pattern*, `HKCU:\Network\*`
  - `Get-ItemProperty`, when not given a property name, returns *all* properties - which in the case at hand are registry *values* - as a "property bag", in the form of a `[pscustomobject]` instance, with the name of the containing *key* reported in the `.PSChildName` property.

Unfortunately, working with PowerShell's registry provider is often not as straightforward as one would like.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dear for your detailed explanation. I really appreciate it. So far below code is working for me and changing the required values but it's showing the error also

Comment: $previousPath = "\\IAPC"
$newPath = "\localhost"
$nPath = HKCU:\Network\*
$getDriverLetter = Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Network\* | Where-Object RemotePath | Select-Object PSChildName
$getDriverPath =Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Network\* | Where-Object RemotePath | Select-Object RemotePath
foreach ($item in $getDriverPath)
{
  $nitem = $item -replace('@{RemotePath=','') -replace('}}','')
  $newPath = $nitem -replace($oldServer,$newServer)
  Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Network\* -Name RemotePath -Value $newPath
}
Error: The term 'HKCU:\Network\*' is not recognized as

Answer (score 0):

@imtiaz Hey i am not sure if you are trying the same but here is how i have achieved recently.

```
$oldServer = "\\abc.local" 
$newServer = "\abc.com"
$paths = REG QUERY HKCU\Network | where{$_ -ne ""}
foreach ($item in $paths)
{
  $oldPath = REG QUERY $item /f RemotePath /t REG_SZ | Out-String
  $oldPath1 = $oldPath.Split()[-12]
  $updatedPath = $oldPath1 -replace $oldServer,$newServer
  reg add $item /v RemotePath /t REG_SZ /d $updatedPath /f /reg:64
}
```

I tried before Get-ItemProperty and set-itemproperty was facing some issues. This might help you. I know this's not a "professional way" but this worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, solution share @mklement0 is the perfect solution. I have tried before your shared one but I'm afraid it will mess with values where remote path values are long. Anyways, thanks and welcome to the forum.